# segmentation fault on FastCGI and wsgi using django

Tags: python, linux, django, fastcgi, gunicorn

I have a django app I'm trying to run on an embedded target running Linux 3.2.35-rt52-2.10.0f0 armv7l.  First, I tried to use fastcgi with lighttpd and I got a segmentation fault. So I tried to use gunicorn to run it using the wsgi.py file

`gunicorn  --bind=0.0.0.0:8000 --workers=2 myapp.wsgi`

it continuously would start new workers as they would fail. I learned that this is because of the segmentation fault as well by running

```
python manage.py runserver
```

in the django app folder. It returned a segmentation fault as well.

wsgi.py :

```
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "myapp.settings")

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

these wsgi settings work just fine on my dev environment.

Does anyone have any suggestions for how to debug this next? could It be Django doesn't work on the embedded target? (arm 7)
I'm at a loss as to how to approach this next.

Comment: what version of python are you using ? i updated my python from 2.7.6 to 2.7.7 and it goes aways.

Comment: I actually gave up and am now switching over to 3.4.3. I'll let you know if I have any success :)